# Access denied error when creating / edit user

Tags: role-management

When I try to add new user or edit existing user and assign some role by clicking 'Member Of' tab and then edit button, I am getting below error.

I am using Sitecore version 10.1.0 (rev. 005207)

[image]

Please help

Comment: Is this an upgraded solution? Also could you please share sitecore. client dll version?

Comment: Did you try this? https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB0848772

Comment: Mahendra Shekhawat yes this is an upgraded solution, sitecore.client.dll version is 16.0.47.0

Comment: Are you using Admin account to add roles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably your `Sitecore.client.dll` version is different in your solution or you don't have proper policies under - `/sitecore/system/Settings/Security/Policies` in core database -

- Check if you have `/sitecore/system/Settings/Security/Policies/Accounts/Can Browse Roles` if not, please create a new one (you can duplicate `/sitecore/system/Settings/Security/Policies/Experience Explorer/Can Explore` so that you don't need to update any security on the item)

[image]

- OR Try to replace your DLL with the vanilla Sitecore instance

The DLL version of `Sitecore.client.dll` you have added is higher version, then `10.1.0` so I am not sure if this is part of any patch or hotfix. So please make sure to check this before replacing the DLL.

Comment: Creating a new item worked for me, Thanks.

Comment: glad it fix the problem. Could you please mark this as an answer?